# @Foreign key is not accepted when I apply Microsoft Clarity SDK in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-chrome

implementation 'com.microsoft.clarity:clarity:1.3.2'

error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration @ForeignKey(entity = FoodDetails.class, parentColumns = "name", childColumns = "item_name", onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE) ^

enter image description here

@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = FoodDetails.class, parentColumns = "name", childColumns = "item_name", onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)) public class CartItem {

enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRCXm.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, **error messages**, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557